# How to only send an email once on form submit by creating a cookie?

Tags: php, forms, cookies

So basically, I have a form that does some calculations.

Once this form is submitted, it will send all the information to me via email.

Although, some users like to do a few calculations until they get it right. For example, they will submit the form many, many times. Therefore, I would not want to get all of these emails, just the first one.

Is there any way of creating a cookie on the first time they submit the form, so that it is only emailed once?

Comment: Can you elaborate `some users like to do a few calculations until they get it right.`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - Sorry about that, just fixed it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['mailsent'])) {
   // send mail!
   setcookie('mailsent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies but a better method would be to use a session to store if the user has already posted your form as cookies can be altered, removed or even never set on the users machine, very easy to by-pass any protection you want to implement. Also adding basic csrf protection is a must for any forms.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['your_vals_ect'])){
    //check csrf
    if(isset($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf']) && $_SESSION['csrf']==$_POST['csrf']){

        if(isset($_SESSION['mail_sent'])){
            //notify the user that they can only submit once or redirect somewhere
        }else{
            //send mail
            mail(...);
            //set the session var
            $_SESSION['mail_sent'] = true;

            //send the user somewhere after or refresh the page to clear the $_POST
            exit(header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        }

    }else{
        //notify user that form must be loaded from site
    }

}else{
    //set a csrf token so user cant post from another site or custom form/request.
    $_SESSION['csrf'] = sha1(uniqid(true));

    //show your form code ect
    //use $_SESSION['csrf'] within a hidden field name="csrf"
}
?>
```

Hope it helps